# gcc 6.1.0 segmentation fault - gcc bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc6

Let's consider follwing code. In fact this is narrowed problem I found using gmock and mocking void(void) method.

```
class Base {
 public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
  void GetValueAndDelete()  { delete this; } //here we crash
};

int main() {
  Derived* p = 0;
  p->GetValueAndDelete();
}
```

Building it with:

```
/tools/gcc6.1/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.1.0
```

with optimization level different than -O0 and running the result causes segmentation fault.

Is it gcc bug or something with c++ code (yes, yes, I know that it uses side effects, but it works with other compilers and without optimization as well)

Comment: you dereference a null pointer, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I would believe that dereferencing a null pointer is grounds for segmentation faults in any circumstance; it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: What? You call a function on a null pointer and wonder why it doesn't work?

Comment: Be very careful when doing `delete this`, it basically is the same as demolishing the building you are in. If you're careful the debris won't kill you, but in most cases bad things are going to happen.

Comment: "it works with other compilers" Do you mean it doesn't print a crash message?

Comment: @BoPersson: Dereferencing null pointer and calling method in this way that does not use any members is fine. What is calling method on pointer? It is simply calling method and passing hidden 'this' argument. Noting is called "on" pointer. Deleting this is nothing special. You should only take care of not using any member after. It is common pattern. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-method-through-null-class-pointer]

Comment: @Kamil_H Are you saying you actually do this in real code?  What software do you develop, so as to warn me not to use it.

Comment: @Kamil - Using `delete this` can be useful, but only if you have an actual object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As I said, gmock/gtest does such things. This is where I found it.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it gcc bug

No.

> or something with c++ code

Yes. You use the arrow operator on a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object. This has undefined behaviour.

> Dereferencing null pointer and calling method in this way that does not use any members is fine.

It's not *fine* according to the standard. It's UB.

> What is calling method on pointer?

Is implementation specific.

> Deleting this is nothing special.

Deleting `this` is very special.

> You should only take care of not using any member after

Yes, that **and** you must make sure that only `new` was used to create all instances on which the function is ever called. No automatic objects, no static objects no `new[]`, no `malloc` + placement new.

So yes, you *can* `delete this`, but be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition here seems to be:

1. `p->` is OK because it is just a syntax for filling in `this`.
2. `delete this` is OK because you don't use `this` after `delete`.

But the above may not actually be OK, because dereferencing a null pointer is always undefined behavior.  Without optimization enabled this may not cause any trouble, because the compiler is doing a "basic compile" which somewhat matches what you imagine when you "compile in your mind."  With optimization, however, GCC will do a lot of things that it normally would not do, such as not bothering to emit "correct" instructions when faced with incorrect source code.  There's literally no need for it to do anything at all when you say `p->` as your program's first act--it could just pretend `main()` was empty (or crash, as in your case).

Comment: Drerferencing nullptr - I agree, but deleting nullptr? It is allowed by standard, isn't it?

Comment: @Kamil_H: You're right, and while I originally didn't think that applied here, on second reading I think it does, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that calling method on nullptr is out of standard, but so far I haven't seen a compiler that wouldn't cope with that in described manner. It seems that gcc6.1 works different (still according to spec). So this is gmock bug. I wonder how many other projects depend on such compiler behavior :)

What is worth to mention is that method is called, 'this' inside is zero as expected and then delete fails. I looked into assembly an there is mov (%rax), %rbx which fails because rax contains zero.